# Are these sentences conditionals?

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

After going through all the conditionals (real and unreal and mixed unreal), I doubt these two types of sentences. Are they conditional sentences?

> He would have been more careful about it if he knew it was so fragile.

What kind of a conditional is this? Is this a mixed one? Unreal past condition and its unreal past result should make the conditional clause  "If he had known it was so fragile, he would have been more careful."

The second example, I presume is NOT a conditional sentence. Please correct me if I am wrong.

> He would have been drinking and driving when the police arrested him.

Comment: "He would have been more careful if he **had known** it was so fragile" is what they call the 'third conditional'.

Comment: Yeah. Some people in the forum get upset by mentioning the number and that is why I said "the past unreal condition with the past unreal result. " "If I knew..." looks more like a past tense than a conditional 2 subjunctive for this to be a mixed-type conditional.

Comment: It's not about 'getting upset', just that native speakers are not taught 'types of conditional'. I, for one, always have to look them up. I meant that **had known** fits the sentence better than **knew**.

Comment: Any sentence (almost) with the word **if** is a conditional. Now, whether it is standard or not is another story. standard is: would have been//had known.

Comment: Another example would be "I would have done it if I knew I had to."  (past unreal if and the past unreal result gives: "I would have done it if I had known I had to.")